# Is there a alternative to using minus in px

Tags: css

I have styled my webpage, all has gone well until i put a centre section in my webpage, which has now pushed my right section down the page, which houses my soon to be floating shopping cart. The centre section is 50% (width) and the right section has a 15% width.
No matter if i change the value of the width the centre section still affects the placement of the right section. The only way the right section will come back up the page to 100px from the top is if i use margin-top: -50px. Which i know is frowned upon. Is there a better way to resolve this issue.

```css
section#cart{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 float: right;
 margin-right: 20px;
 margin-top: 100px;
 width: 15% !important;
 border: 1px solid #808284;
 height: 200px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 }

p#order{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #e86065;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

p#estimated{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #d5e16d;
    width:100%;
    height: 80px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-top: 5px;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
}

b#avg{
font-size: 2.5em;
color: #00a4c0;
text-align: center;
}

/*PRODUCTS VIEW- MIDDLE*/
section#products_view{
margin: auto;
width: 50%;
background-color: red;
height: 400px;
margin-top: 110px;
  
}
```

```html
<section id='products_view'>
        <p>hello<p>
        </section>
        

        <section id='cart'>
            <p id='order'>My Order</p>
            <div id='del'>
                <p id='estimated'>Estimated Delivery <br>
                    <b id='avg'><?php echo $rest_avg ?></b><br>
                    minutes</p>  
                <?php // if (isset($_GET[''])) {
                    ?>
            </div>

        </section>
```

Comment: you can use position:fixed;top:0;right:0;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by creating a three column structure with flexbox. I'm using a `:before` pseudo element for the left column.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.container:before {
  content: "";
}
.container:before, #cart {
  flex: 1;
}
#cart {
  background: grey;
}
#products_view {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: silver;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section id='products_view'>
    hello
  </section>
  <section id='cart'>
    cart
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. didn't know you could do that.